# How can I convert a string to DateTime with specific format?

Tags: linux, bash, datetime

I can't see any way to specify a parsing format for `date`, and my input format is not recognized:

```
dt1=`date --date="20151020T113100.475"`; echo $dt1  # fails with 'invalid date'
```

Comment: What do you mean? You want to give a date in one format and get it in another format?

Comment: Either `date` understands the format or it doesn't. Depending on your system the capabilities vary. If you want more control, you need to use something more powerful, like Perl's built-in `Time::Piece` module, which allows you to specify a format string.

Comment: Yes. I have 2 datetimes in %Y%d%dT%H%M%S.%N format. I want to compare them

Comment: *How* do you want to compare them? The format you describe (ISO) is pretty optimal for comparison as the subfields are sorted in order of significance already; I don't see why you'd want to *convert* that in the first place, to what format, and why you'd need `date` for that?

Comment: @DevSolar Yes BUT this is a bash STRING - it is not some sort of ISO type - hence I need to convert it first...

Comment: This is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. And since the components are already sorted by significance, you can check for greater / smaller simply by doing a string comparison (which was one of the rationales behind ISO 8601).

Comment: @DevSolar So if I say :  

dt1="20151020T113100.475"; dt2="20151020T113200.475"; 
if [[ $dt1 < $dt2 ]]; then
  # your logic here..
  printf "less than..\n";
else
  # your logic here..
  printf "greater than or equal..\n";
fi

Comment: @ManInMoon: Exactly.

Comment: Surely that's just a STRING comparison? How do I check if dt1 is more that 60 seconds older than dt2?

Comment: @ManInMoon: That is why I asked for the "how" of your comparison. You don't want to *just compare* them, you want to make *calculations* on them (i.e. compare `dt1` to `dt2` *plus 60 seconds*). That means a mere string comparison won't work, but that was not clear from your question. (Use @<username> to make sure a user gets notified of a comment, I almost missed this.)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by DevSolar, if you arent doing any other date processing with these values, can just use

```
if [[ $dt1 < $dt2 ]]; then
  # your logic here..
  printf "less than..\n";
else
  # your logic here..
  printf "greater than or equal..\n";
fi
```

---

if you need to convert these to date form and/or want to validate the string input, can use bash substring extraction :

```
$ dt1="20151020T113100.475"
$ date -d "${dt1:0:4}-${dt1:4:2}-${dt1:6:2} ${dt1:9:2}:${dt1:11:2}:${dt1:13:6}"
Tue Oct 20 11:31:00 AEDT 2015
```

output formats can be applied also here eg :

```
$ date -d "${dt1:0:4}-${dt1:4:2}-${dt1:6:2} ${dt1:9:2}:${dt1:11:2}:${dt1:13:6}" +"%s"
1445301060
```

here %s gives seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC

so to compare with another date ( `dt2` ), can use something like

```
dt1="20151020T113100.475"
dt2="20151021T113100.475"
ts1=$(date -d "${dt1:0:4}-${dt1:4:2}-${dt1:6:2} ${dt1:9:2}:${dt1:11:2}:${dt1:13:6}" +"%s")
ts2=$(date -d "${dt2:0:4}-${dt2:4:2}-${dt2:6:2} ${dt2:9:2}:${dt2:11:2}:${dt2:13:6}" +"%s")
if ((ts1<ts2)); then
  # your logic here..
  printf "less than..\n"
else
  # your logic here..
  printf "greater than or equal..\n"
fi
```

which outputs

```
less than..
```

see **[man date](http://www.manpages.info/linux/date.1.html)** for valid output formats

Comment: If all you get out of it is greater / equal vs. less, you could just do `if [[ $dt1 < $dt2 ]]` without any prior conversion...

Comment: yes, if that is the only thing user wants to do with this date info

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, there are a number of different ways to approach this problem. As correctly noted, the key is finding a format that `date -d "string"` with consider a valid date/time string. Starting with the original string:

```
20151020T113100.475
```

One close format that date will accept is:

```
20151020 11:31:00.475
```

Getting the current string into the new format, just takes a few iterations of substring removal and piecing back together again. A short script that would work is:

```
#!/bin/bash

d="20151020T113100.475"

dt=${d%T*}          ## 20151020
tm=${d#*T}          ## 113100.475
tfrac=${tm#*.}      ## 475
tm=${tm%.$tfrac}    ## 113100

## add : between time components
for ((i = 0; i < ${#tm}; i+=2)); do
    nt=$nt:${tm:$i:2}
done
nt=${nt:1}          ## 11:31:00
nt=${nt}.$tfrac     ## 11:31:00.475

echo "date : '$(date -d "$dt $nt" +"%x %X (+.%N nanosecs)")'"

exit 0
```

**Output**

```
$ bash parsedtstamp4.sh
date : '10/20/2015 11:31:00 AM (+.475000000 nanosec)'
```